# importing a c# class in a cshtml view

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is this possible? Iterating through a list, I cannot use its actual class to be used as a variable type when storing data in a for each loop.

```
@using MyFirstWebApplication.Models.Student
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstWebApplication.Models.Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

@foreach (Student student in Model)
{
    <h2>Student Name: @student.FirstName @student.LastName</h2>
}
```

Code will compile only when the variable type in the foreach loop is 'var'

Comment: Take the @using statement out altogether and just replace Student with var.

Comment: What's wrong with using `var`?

Comment: Haha that is one thing I noticed and did. Nothing wrong with var!
Just found it to be particularly odd that I couldn't use Student as a variable type.

Answer (score 7):

Your @using statement looks incorrect. Assuming the full name of the class is MyFirstWebApplication.Models.Student, the using statement should be:

```
@using MyFirstWebApplication.Models
```

Comment: I wish I could upvote both of you guys :(
Are we not allowed to import one particular class like in Java?
Do I always have to import the whole folder?

Comment: @LinhSaysHi you are not importing any folder. You are importing mere namespace. Namespaces are used to place the classes virtually separate. Don't worry. This is not going to hit the application runtime performance.

Comment: The c# using statement is very different from Java's. The C# using statement imports the whole namespace, as @Bilal mentioned, while Java's imports a single class. MSDN has more info. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Comment: @LinhSaysHi You can upvote both, but you can only accept one. In the case where the answers are largely the same, I usually pick the first. But if one answer is better than the other, I usually pick that one.

Answer (score 3):

your using statement looks a little incorrect. 
Try this :

```
@using MyFirstWebApplication.Models
@model IEnumerable<MyFirstWebApplication.Models.Student>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Title";
}

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

@foreach (Student student in Model)
{
    <h2>Student Name: @student.FirstName @student.LastName</h2>
}
```

Does this help ?

Further:

> Are we not allowed to import one particular class like in Java? Do I
>   always have to import the whole folder?

Although its not exactly the same as you imagine, you can use namespace alias.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

This will let you import classes directly from other namespaces like this:

```
 using Project = PC.MyCompany.Project;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a using statement to the top of the `.cshtml` file, you can have it implicitly added to each page by configuration. Then you don't have to go modify every Razor file. Don't repeat yourself.

To do this, locate the `web.config` file in your `~/Views` folder (not the main one in your application root) and add the following configuration where appropriate:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
         <add namespace="MyFirstWebApplication.Models" /> <!-- This will probably be the only line you need to add -->
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This isn't the answer to question, but I glad you put it there because I dint know this. (y)

Comment: @BilalFazlani It doesn't directly answer the question. But the underlying question was clearly "how do I reference types in other namespaces in my Razor views?" And this is a much cleaner way of accomplishing that than adding a `using` statement to each Razor file.

Comment: This is very interesting! I do appreciate this answer, as now I know there exist another means of importing and may be better suited for certain applications

Comment: @mason On second thought, yes I agree. It is a cleaner way to do it.